# Anyone have problems with notch on ios 13.4.1 ( newest version )

Tags: quasar-framework

Anyone have problems with notch on ios 13.4.1 ( newest version ) . using Ionic webview or Wkwebview ???

My toolbar ends op in the ios statusbar - even on an new quasar app install.

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in in Quasar 10.1: 
https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/releases/tag/quasar-v1.10.0

You can quickly upgrade Quasar
https://quasar.dev/start/upgrade-guide

```
# run these commands inside
# of a Quasar v1 project

# check for upgradable packages
$ quasar upgrade

# do the actual upgrade
$ quasar upgrade --install
```